# Django Adding Password Reset to Custom Models

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on site with two models College and Employee .
I used auth_views Password Reset views and was able to do working password reset for model User but whatever I try I am unable to implement it for Custom models(Employee and College)

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="None")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Minimum of 8 Characters")
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
   
class College(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="None")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Minimum of 8 Characters")
    college = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Views.py**

```
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = College.objects.filter(Q(email=data))
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    email_template_name = "password_reset_email.txt"
                    c = {
                    "email":user.email,
                    'domain':'127.0.0.1:8000',
                    'site_name': 'Two Factor',
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    "user": user,
                    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                    'protocol': 'http',
                    }
                    email = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                    try:
                        send_mail(subject, email, 'myemailaddress' , [user.email], fail_silently=False)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    return redirect ("password_reset_done")
    password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="password_reset.html",context={"password_reset_form":password_reset_form})



def password_reset_confirm(request,uidb64,token):
   def get(self, request, uidb64, token, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            print(uid)
            user = College.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user=None

        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            if request.method == "POST":
              password=request.POST['password']
              College.objects.filter(emp_id=uid).update(password=password)
              College.save()
              return redirect('logi')
             
            return render(request,'password_reset_confirm.html',{})      
            
        else:
         
            return render(request,'password_reset_confirm.html',{})
        return render(request,'password_reset_confirm.html',{})
   return render(request,'password_reset_confirm.html',{})
```

**urls.py**

```
     path("password_reset_done", auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    #url(r'^password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
             #   core_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_complete.html"), name='password_reset_complete'), 
    path("password_reset", core_views.password_reset_request, name="password_reset") ,
```

Is there any tutorial to implement Password reset for Custom Models or anything I should do in my code ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` in settings. Related Documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Ok I will try that but I have 2  Custom User Models